# Java - Multithread - HTTP GET- Why getting faster with more open connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, caching

I want to test my application if it can handle many Request parallel. To test this i simply initialised the Request about 50 times. Each Request in a own Thread.

The `run()` Method looks `sth`. like this with a bit more Stuff.

```
public void run(){
    URL getUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) getUrl.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(data);
            }
            br.close();
}
```

The stragne thing is that with more Request the time per Request is reducing significant to about **50%**. Why is this happening? Does the Java HTTP Connection cache the Request?

Comment: Connections might be held open.  It could also be JVM statistics "warm up".

Comment: "warming up" is no the case i waited a few min until i did the measure. How could i force to open a new connection in each thread?

Comment: "Waited a few minutes" - did you do some stretches?  No, this is what I mean: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html